# Issue with memory allocation while attempting to make a hash table in C

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, heap-memory

I have been trying to implement a hash table that would work as a dictionary in C and although it seems that I am done with some basic parts, the table doesnt work as intended.

These are my data types, the definitions of the API and the way I am retrieving data from a sample file, line by line wit a separator of **->**

```
typedef struct entry {

    const char *misspelling;

    const char *correct_word;

} entry_t;

typedef struct table {

    size_t size;

    size_t used_entries;

    entry_t **entries;

    size_t seed;

} table_t;
```

```
static entry_t *
entry_init(const char *const misspelling, const char *const correct_word)
{
    entry_t *entry = malloc(sizeof(entry_t));
    entry->misspelling = misspelling;
    entry->correct_word = correct_word;

    return entry;
}

static void
entry_delete(entry_t *entry)
{
    free(entry->correct_word);
    free(entry->misspelling);
    free(entry);
}

table_t *
table_init(const size_t size)
{

    table_t *table = malloc(sizeof(table_t));
    table->entries = malloc(size * sizeof(entry_t *));
    table->seed = get_prime();
    table->size = size;
    table->used_entries = 0U;

    return table;
}

void
table_destroy(table_t *table)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < table->size; i++) {

        entry_t *it = table->entries[i];

        if (it && it->correct_word && it->misspelling) {
            entry_delete(it);
        }
    }

    free(table->entries);
    free(table);
}

size_t
table_insert(table_t *table, const char *const misspelling,
    const char *const correct_word)
{
    entry_t *entry = NULL;
    size_t index = 0;
    size_t position = 0;

    while (position != table->size) {

        // calculate hash of the string based on linear probing
        index = hash_string(table->seed, table->size, misspelling,
            position);

        // retrieve the entry of the table to check wether it exists or
        // not
        entry = table->entries[index];

        // entry doesnt exist so we write to them
        if (!entry) {
            entry = entry_init(misspelling, correct_word);

            table->used_entries++;
            return index;
        }

        position++;
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}

const char *
table_get(const table_t *const table, const char *const misspelling)
{
    size_t index = 0;

    entry_t *entry = NULL;

    for (size_t iteration = 0; iteration < table->size; ++iteration) {

        index = hash_string(table->seed, table->size, misspelling,
            iteration);

        entry = table->entries[index];

        if (entry && strcmp(misspelling, entry->misspelling) == 0) {

            return entry->correct_word;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

table_t *
initialize_vocabulary(const char *const file_name)
{
    char *line = NULL, *misspelled_word = NULL, *correct_word = NULL;

    FILE *fp = NULL;

    unsigned long len = 0;

    long read = 0;
    
    table_t *table = table_init(INITIAL_SIZE);

    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {

        misspelled_word = strtok(line, DELIMS);
        correct_word = strtok(NULL, DELIMS);

        table_insert(table, misspelled_word, correct_word);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    free(line);

    return table;
}
```

I tried using that but upon get, everything I get back is **NULL**. I also used **Valgrind** to see what is happening in the memory and this is the result

```
==8331== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8331==     in use at exit: 432 bytes in 27 blocks
==8331==   total heap usage: 32 allocs, 5 frees, 5,392 bytes allocated
==8331== 
==8331== Searching for pointers to 27 not-freed blocks
==8331== Checked 115,600 bytes
==8331== 
==8331== 432 bytes in 27 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==8331==    at 0x4848899: malloc (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==8331==    by 0x494D599: entry_init (table.c:13)
==8331==    by 0x494D538: table_insert (table.c:120)
==8331==    by 0x494D745: initialize_vocabulary (api.c:32)
==8331==    by 0x10917A: main (driver.c:102)
```

Line 13 in **table.c** refers to the **malloc** call in entry_init.

I also used the debugger to go step by step on the inserting process (I do not think that there might be an issue with my get function) and I saw that while the hashing works good and the assignment from **entry=entry_init(misspelling, corrected_word)** doesnt fail, upon every different insert the the **entries** are always NULL.

mMy assumption is that, I am allocating something, it is not visible in the actual data structure and since it is always NULL, the **destroy_table** function never deallocates the memory.

BTW the initial size that is passed on the **intiialize_vocabulary** is 30 and the actual number of elements I am inserting is 27.

Any idea of what the issue might be?

Any other tips on the code to improve it?

EDIT:

Here are the hashing functions as well as main:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "hash.h"

#define HASH 5

// generate a random 32 bit prime integer
size_t
get_prime(void)
{
    size_t number = 0;

    srand((unsigned int)time((NULL)));

    number = (unsigned int)rand();

    while (number % 2 != 0) {
        number++;
    }

    return number;
}

// algorithm for hashing a string based on djb2 , Dan Bernstein
static size_t
hash(size_t seed, const char *key)
{
    size_t hash = seed;

    size_t c = 0;

    while ((c = (size_t)*key++)) {
        hash = ((hash << HASH) + hash) + c; // hash * 33 + c
    }

    return hash;
}

// iterable hashing with linnear probing, good for ascii english words
size_t
hash_string(const size_t seed, size_t table_size, const char *const key,
    size_t it)
{

    unsigned long position = hash(seed, key);

    position = position + it * (position * 2 + 1);

    return position % table_size;
}

int
main(void)
{
    table_t *table = initialize_vocabulary("data/miss1");

    char * word = table_get(table, "abilties");

    table_destroy(table);
}
```

Comment: Where's the `main()` function? Where's the `hash_string()` function?

Comment: Please note that [`getline`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) is *not* required to reallocate the buffer it stores the string into. That means you could have multiple entries pointing to the same buffer. Also note that when `getline` reallocates, the old pointers you have will become invalid. In short: Always *duplicate* the strings for your table entries.

Comment: Also note that unless you have a perfect hashing algorithm or a large enough table, you *will* get collisions where two different entries point to the same bucket. You need to be able to handle that correctly.

Comment: Why do you not check the return value of `malloc()`, `strtok()` and `fopen()`?

Comment: Furthermore your `entry_delete` function will call `free` passing the pointers you received by calling `strtok` on the string that `getline` created. Since `strtok` doesn't duplicate the strings, and neither do you, these pointers were not returned by `malloc` (or similar function) and you can't pass them to `free`.

Comment: Hi! StackOverflow wont allow me to edit the question and iclude them, so I will try to explain them here. Main calls init vocabulary with an argument to the data file, then I am calling the table_get function with an existing word and then I am destroying the table with table_destroy. On what concerns the hasing function, it is based on djb2 hashing function so there isnt anything shady or not tested behind that (copy pasted it)

Comment: There's an `Edit` link just below the tags. You should always be able to edit your own questions. And just to be on the safe side, here's another [edit] link.

Comment: This information should be a part of the question, the `main()` and `hash_string()` should be part of the question. Your example is not reproducible.

Comment: I was thinking about it actually, using the strdup function in order to prevent any access to not dynamically allocted memory

Comment: "There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later." this is literally what the button says

Comment: To summarize my thoughts, I think you need to spend some time to refresh the basics of strings and how to duplicate them. I also recommend you read a little more about hash-tables, buckets and collisions and common ways to work around collisions (for example using *linked lists*).

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help, but is not the point of my question. As I mentioned, the main issue is the memory allocation that is not visible while iterating, I get it that there are issues with parsing the file but I guess I cant see any results in the program if there is nothing to display due to faulty insert function

Comment: I'm assuming this is a learning project, as this is a solved problem with many header libraries that offer great solutions...? if so, consider if using primes is really the way you want to approach this. also note that `entry = table->entries[index]` might give you index `176264538765`... you should really limit that to `entry = table->entries[index % limit]` (this is where log 2 performance shines).

Comment: Hi @Myst, yes, this is a learning project  and yes the hash_string function returns the number under modulo table_size. EDIT I managed to upload the code inthe post

Comment: "the main issue is the memory allocation that is not visible while iterating" Your program has some serious bugs noted in the comments. They are your issue. You need to fix every one of them.

Comment: How is `get_prime` a prime? it's just an odd integer (`while` could have been replaced with `number | 1`... also, `rand()` gives 31 bit randomness as a best case scenario, and your `prime` might be too small (i.e., `11`)... which will be somewhat useless. Usually pre-computed prime tables are used (another win for the log 2 approach).

Comment: ++issues: your `hash` function will likely overflow the string length, i.e., if string length is less than `sizeof(size_t)` ... also, you assume the string ends with `sizeof(size_t)` zero bytes... which is unlikely, as most strings have a single `NUL` byte (if we remember to put it there). More likely that the `hash` function overflows and loops until your program crashes from a `read` overflow.